# A for loop reads an image and returns a list of integers in square brackets. However, it is not formatted correctly

Tags: python, regex, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to add square brackets. Have been attempting to use 'regex' for this, without success.

Attempts at this has produced many error messages.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback   
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__   
    return self.func(*args)    
  File "/home/grumpy/other-stuff/change-pixel.py", line 167, in array   
    data = re.sub(r'(])', r'\1]]', data)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 210, in sub   
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)  
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

This is the most encountered.
The data structure is;

```
[[[255, 255, 255] <- needs '[[
[255, 255, 255] 
[255, 255, 255] 
[255, 255, 255] 
[255, 255, 255]]  And every 578 lines it needs
[[255, 255, 255]  And every 579 lines
[255, 255, 255] 
[255, 255, 255] 
[255, 255, 255]
[255, 255, 255]  <- needs ']]'
```

The code is

```
for y1 in range(y):
   for x1 in range(x):
        R1, G1, B1 = rgb_im.getpixel((y1, x1)) 
        if R1 == r1 and G1 == g1 and B1 == b1:
            R1 = r2;  G1 = g2;  B1 = b2 
        data = [y1, x1,R1, G1, B1]
        if x1 == x and y1 == y: break 
        if x1 < x:
            x1 = x1 + 1
        if x1 == x:
            data = re.sub(r'(])', r'\1]]', data)  <-- ERROR POINT
            y1 = y1 + 1
        print (data)
        arry = np.array(data, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Also, every thing in the list is integers, and must stay that way
However, the square brackets are strings.

Comment: The square brackets are part of the display of a list or array.  The double brackets denote a nested list (list of lists) or a 2d array.  If the list or array is properly structured the brackets are automatic.

Comment: I created the list, and manipulated the values to my desire. For the data to be excepted by PIL to create another image the format must be corrected.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't manipulate or format a list like this.  I think you need to create a list of lists or an equivalent `numpy` array. Try `x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, and `X = np.array(x)`.  Now `print` `x` and `X`.

Comment: To correct the format so it is except able for PIL to create another image with the changes included. I did not use a PIL function to read the image. Hence the double for loop. The replacement values came for user input. If the formatting works, the program is finished.

Comment: hpaulj, I do understand what your getting at. This is what you get from functions that read images. I used double for statements and getpixel() to read the image. The formatting  of getpiel() does not provide this format. SO, I have to do this myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed to provide information. I'm running python3.8 and all modules have been updated. On a Linux platform, mint20.

Comment: Program and module versions aren't a problem.  The difficulty lies you own understanding of what an array is and how create and manipulate it.

Comment: hpaulj ; What you say is very correct. This is why the post was posted. If I had good understanding of this it would be finished. After having read my post, several .pdf books on the suject, it still is not clear. Point me in the write direction, I'll read it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a change that may set you on the right track.

```
arr = np.zeros((y, x, 3), dtype=np.uint8)    # a "blank" array of the right size
for y1 in range(y):
   for x1 in range(x):
        R1, G1, B1 = rgb_im.getpixel((y1, x1)) 
        if R1 == r1 and G1 == g1 and B1 == b1:
            R1 = r2;  G1 = g2;  B1 = b2 
        arr[y1, x1, :] = [R1, G1, B1]    # set a "pixel' value
```

An alternative is

```
alist = []
for y1 in range(y):
   blist = []
   for x1 in range(x):
        R1, G1, B1 = rgb_im.getpixel((y1, x1)) 
        if R1 == r1 and G1 == g1 and B1 == b1:
            R1 = r2;  G1 = g2;  B1 = b2 
        blist.append([R1, G1, B1])
   alist.append(blist)
   # make a nested list of lists (of lists)
arr = np.array(alist)  # should also be a (y,x,3) array
```

Print `alist` or `arr` to see how the brackets are just a part of the display.  Commas, spaces, and new lines are also part of the display.  They aren't strings in either the list or the array.